# GWT app to phoneGap works without phoneGap Javascript include

Tags: gwt, cordova

I created a simple GWT UI and compiled it,  dropped the generated javascript onto my android app and ran it. Everything worked fine, then I noticed that I did not actually include the cordova.2.2.0.js file in my HTML page but the UI still displayed fine on my phone.  How is this?  What there fore is the cordova2.2.0.js  javascript file needed for?  My app did only consist of a few buttons and text boxes so maybe simple stuff works out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cordova.js is responsible for native phone API access like storage, camera and so on. So you will not receive device events and will have no access to device native functions without it.